# Greatest common divisors in Integral Domain

Tags: ring-theory

Let $R$ be an integral domain and $r,s\in R-\{0\}$ such that $\text{gcd}(r,s)=g.$ Suppose $\text{gcd}(kr,ks)$ exists, where $k \in R -\{0\}.$ Could anyone advise me on how to prove $kg= \text{gcd}(kr,ks)$ ?

Hints will suffice, thank you.

Comment: Let $d = \gcd(kr,ks)$. Since $kg \mid kr$ and $kg\mid ks$, we have $d = kgb$. Deduce that $gb\mid r$ and $gb\mid s$ and from that that $b$ is a unit.

Answer (score 1):

Here in we denote: x\y <==> x divides y. Since g = gcd{r,s}, g\r and g\s. Thus there are p, and q in R such that: r = pg, and s = qg. So kr = kpg = p(kg),and so kg\kr. Similarly: kg\ks. Now if t\kr and t\ks, we show: t\kg. t\kr ==> kr = tu, and ks = tv ==> r = k^(-1)*tu, and s = k^(-1)*tv ==> k^(-1)*t divides both r, and s. So k^(-1)*t divides gcd{r,s} = g. So g = w(k^(-1)*t) ==> kg = wt ==> t\kg ==> kg = gcd{kr,ks}.

Comment: Thank you. But I would greatly appreciate that you provide hints instead of solution.

Comment: the hint is: you use: a) inverse and b) definition of gcd. that is: x = gcd{a,b} iff x\a and x\b and if y\a and y\b then y\x.